# How to cancel editing item in CListCtrl

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc

Using `ClistCtrl::EditLabel`, edit window is created.

When pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> key the editing is getting cancelled.

How to cancel editing item in `CListCtrl` using code without sending `VM_RETURN` or `VM_ESCAPE` key message?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`CListCtrl::CancelEditLabel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cb92w6w.aspx).